# How to encode image to send over Python HTTP server?

Tags: image, http, python-3.x, server, encode

I would like some help on my following handler:

```
 class MyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
     def do_HEAD(client):
        client.send_response(200)
        client.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        client.end_headers()
     def do_GET(client):
        if client.path == "/":
           client.send_response(200)
           client.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
           client.end_headers()

           client.wfile.write(load('index.html'))

 def load(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as file:
    return encode(str(file.read()))

 def encode(file):
    return bytes(file, 'UTF-8')
```

I've got this, the function `load()` is someone else in the file. Sending a HTML page over my HTTP handler seems to be working, but how can I send an image? How do I need to encode it and what `Content-type` should I use?

Help is greatly appreciated!

(PS: I would like the image that is send to be seen in the browser if I connect to my httpserver)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a PNG image you have to set the content-type to "image/png". For jpg: "image/jpeg".

Other Content types can be found [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html).

Edit: Yes, I forgot about encoding in my first edit.

The answer is: You don't! When you load your image from a file, it is in the correct encoding already.

I read about your codec problem: The problem is, as much I see in your load function. Don't try to encode the file content.

You may use for binary data this:

```
def load_binary(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file_handle:
        return file_handle.read()
```

Comment: When I change 'r' to 'rb' it loads for 3 minutes or so and I have 1000 lines of random words...

Comment: I just tried your load_binary but then I get this error: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 600: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: In this case, the method client.wfile.write does expect ascii data. I don't know the webserver you use -- maybe there is a different method for binary data?

Comment: it might be because im encoding it with 'UTF-8'.. should I encode it with something else?

Comment: No. Problem here is, that you are working with Python 3, as it seems. I have not so much experience with it yet. But the trouble with Python (2 & 3) is the encoding stuff. You must read the file as binary file, else Python will try to read it as text and that can not work with binary files. I changed my code above. Could you try this? ('rb' instead of 'r'). I hope, that the http module then will send the unencoded binary data.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Juergen you have to set the accordingly content-type.
This example I found may help you: https://github.com/tanzilli/playground/blob/master/python/httpserver/example2.py

The example is in Python 2, but the changes should be minor.

Ah and it's better to use `self` instead of `client` -> see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments), Python's style guide

Comment: this was kind of useful, but it's NOT easy to transition from python 2 to 3 because in python 3 you have to encode all the data into bytes... otherwise it won't work, I just tested.

Comment: I should have given more information... Line `39` has to be changed. You have to open it in binary mode: `f = open(curdir + sep + self.path, 'rb')`

Moreover the print statements and the import (`from http.server import [...]` instead of `from BaseHTTPServer import [...]`) must be changed.